# One Chrome browser window in selenium webdriver --python

Tags: python-2.7, selenium-webdriver, initialization

I have some issue with the init constructor related to selenium webdriver's chrome instances.

Here are the pieces of my scripts:

*First one named methods.py*

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import paths
class PagePatterns(object):


def __init__(self, title=None):
    self.driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\Python27\chromedriver.exe')
    self.title = title

def get_page_title(self):
    return self.get_driver().title
```

*Second one named login.py*

```
from utils.methods import PagePatterns
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from utils import paths

methods = PagePatterns()

class LoginPage(object):
def login(self):
    country_choose = (By.XPATH, paths.country_list_login)
    methods.click(country_choose)
```

*Next one - register.py*

```
from utils.methods import PagePatterns
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from utils import utils, paths
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait

methods = PagePatterns()

class MainPage(object):

def open_homepage(self):
    methods.open_base_page()
    title_check = methods.get_page_title()
    assert title_check == paths.page_title
```

*The last one main_test.py is using LoginPage class*

```
from register import MainPage
from login import LoginPage

MainPage().open_homepage()
LoginPage().login()
```

That's all about the code. My question is - when I am running main_test.py Chrome is called two times (two windows), but I want only one window of the browser - how to make it?

Thanks.

Comment: where is `self.get_driver()` defined?

Comment: self.get_driver() is in methods.py and now i just put self.driver outside __init__ - and it works.